# What are the recurrences equivalent to algebraic generating functions?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Consider a sequence $a(n)$. It is well known that $a(n)$ satisfies a linear recurrence with constant coefficients if and only if its ordinary generating function is rational, and that $a(n)$ satisfies a linear recurrence with coefficients polynomial in $n$ if and only if its ordinary generating function is holonomic (D-finite).

Is there a nice description of the class of recurrences corresponding to algebraic generating functions (an important class which sits between rational and holonomic functions)?

Comment: The answer is close to being "recurrences corresponding to unambiguous context-free languages" but I don't think it's an exact correspondence. There should be some discussion of this in Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics vol. II*.

Comment: A proof that algebraic functions are holonomic might help. Also $P(f(z),z)=0$ gives a (bit messy) recurrence for the coefficients.

Comment: Interesting question. I didn't know the term "holonomic" ... in this context.